# How to convert encoding from ASCII-8BIT to another, without passing through UTF-8 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

```
irb(main):010:0> str = "sar\xE0".force_encoding "ASCII-8BIT"
irb(main):011:0> str.encode 'ISO-8859-1', "ASCII-8BIT"
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE0" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
    from (irb):11:in `encode'
    from (irb):11
    from /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I have a string as `ASCII-8BIT` (binary), and I want to bring it to another encoding, but it seems that every conversion tries to convert it before to `utf-8` and so it fails (basically it forces me to substitute undefined chars).

Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Comment: removed the whole file references, they were not necessary

Comment: Okay, so if `"sar\xE0".b` is your input, what is your expected output?

Comment: should be `sarà`, but this is an example.. don't think is relevant.

Comment: `"sarà"` in UTF-8 or in ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Comment: I need ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a string in binary (`ASCII-8BIT`) encoding:

```
str = "sar\xE0".b #=> "sar\xE0"
str.encoding      #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

You can tell Ruby that this string is actually in ISO-8859-1 via [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding):

```
str.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1') #=> "sar\xE0"
str.encoding                     #=> #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
```

Note that you still see `\xE0` because Ruby does not attempt to convert the character.

Printing the string on a UTF-8 terminal gives:

```
puts str
sar�
```

The [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) � is shown, because `0xE0` is an invalid byte in UTF-8.

Printing the same string on a ISO-8859-1 terminal however gives:

```
puts str
sarà
```

To work with the string in Ruby, you usually want to convert it to UTF-8 via [`encode!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-encode-21):

```
str.encode!('UTF-8') #=> "sarà"
str.encoding         #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Or in a single step by passing both, the destination encoding and the source encodings to `encode!`:

```
str = "sar\xE0".b                  #=> "sar\xE0"
str.encode!('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') #=> "sarà"
str.encoding                       #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: So basically my problem is that I am trying to jump directly from "ASCII-8BIT" to another one?

Comment: @ciaoben to set the binary string's encoding to ISO-8859-1, you just have to call `force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')` as shown above. Are you facing another problem?

Comment: Nono your solution makes sense. Just want to understand because it gives me a "double conversion" when try to encode directly from ascii-8bit. It tries to do ASCII-8BIT -> UTF-8 -> ISO-8859-1  (see the error in the question)

Comment: @ciaoben yes, it seems that Ruby is trying to convert to UTF-8 as a common "base" but that doesn't cause the conversion to fail. The problem is that there's no default mapping to or from binary encoding – the bytes could mean anything. There's one exception, though: `encode` (with binary) does work if all bytes are between 0 to 127, because they map to the same characters in virtually any encoding. It fails however if the string contains a byte between 128 and 255. In that case, you have to tell `encode` the string's actual encoding.